# Initialise and reuse objects in C#

Tags: c#

I have two classes:

```
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    private List<OrderLine> OLines; 
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

My Code will, at a given time, have only one instance of the Orders Class but Orders class can have multiples instances of OrderLines

What is the cleanest way to create objects and discard them whenever required in the code ?

Will this suffice?

```
private Orders sampleorder;

if (sampleorder ==null)
{
    sampleorder = new Orders();
}
else
{
    sampleorder = null;
    sampleorder = new Orders();
}
```

What I am trying to do is at start I want to initialise the object and then, when order is completed, I want to cleanup all members of that object and reuse it from beginning with initialised values.

Comment: don't reuse objects. the garbage collector is pretty smart.

Comment: You dont need to 'discard' any objects. The garbage collector does this for you. There are some exceptions to this, but in your particular case you dont have to.

Comment: How can I reuse the same object with all its members initialised

Comment: Create it again. The old reference is discarded automatically..

Comment: @JanetOhara - You don't reuse objects. You just create new ones when you need them.

Comment: It looks like you've already solved your problem. You don't need to check if `sampleorder` is null, or even set it to null. Just allocate a new `Orders` instance whenever you need a brand new object.

Comment: so the above code is fine then or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: To be honest there is no need for the if/else. You could just always set `sampleorder = new Orders();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "discard" you may mean

**Freeing the memory used by the object:**

> It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but
>   most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create
>   performance issues.

<sup>[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)</sup>

**Using an entirely new object in the same variable/property:**

In this case, simply create a new instance of the object, assign it to the variable/property and let the garbage collector do his job to clean the unused references

Comment: so that means when I am done processing one order then to initialise before i work with the next order I simply have to call this  
 
 sampleorder = new Orders();
 
 I was just afraid that if I call sampleorder= null and then use this for next order then garbage collector will get called later
 and mess up the current order I am working with

Comment: Exactly. your sampleorder is just a place where you store a reference to your object.

Answer (score 0):

Well objects are automatically disposed of when they are out of scope. So you want the parent object "Orders" to stay active while it's inner objects are to be deleted.

If you're going to have one instance of the parent object. Consider using "[KeepAlive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx)" so you can keep the parent object alive as long you'd like (aka out of it's normal scope). Then, when using this parent object (orders), manually [dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx) of its members (OrderId, Olines) when they aren't needed anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This would make you sure you have a list inside your class all the time.

```
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    private List<OrderLine> oLines;
    public List<OrderLine> OLines
    {
        get
        {
            if (oLines == null)
                oLines = new List<OrderLine>();
            return oLines;
        }
    }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```